# How to exclusively use long polling with InteractiveServer render mode? .NET8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have some Blazor components that will be rendered in interactive mode, eg:

```
@rendermode InteractiveServer
```

By default, I believe SignalR with websockets is used for this render mode. I don't want this because for my purposes websockets are too costly, prone to connection timeouts which is unacceptable to end users on poor connections, and the interactivity needed is very minimal anyway. I'd vastly prefer long polling.

What is the idiomatic way to exclusively use long polling without websockets for InteractiveServer render mode in .NET 8?

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place? `websockets are too costly` it's the exact opposite - Websockets cost nothing when there are no changes. It's long polling that's expensive, whether there are any changes or not. Whatever problem you may have won't be solved by long polling

Comment: `prone to connection timeouts` and long polling isn't? (it is actually, and more expensive to reconnect). It seems that the real problem is the bad network, not websockets. In that case *don't* use Blazor-server. Blazor WASM runs on the client and only talks to the server to retrieve or send data.

Comment: `the interactivity needed is very minimal anyway.` if that's the case, don't use Blazor at all, or use server-side rendering only with minimal scripting in Javascript or WASM. What kind of interactivity *do* you need? Why pick Blazor in the first place?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My issue is that I need to set local storage jwt token. Can I do that with WASM?

Comment: Should be configured with `app.MapBlazorHub` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0#blazor-hub-options

Comment: It only support websocket  now,here's an issue related  on github:https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/470

Answer (score 1):

To use long polling instead of websockets in Blazor 8 interactive server, disable the autostart of Blazor

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js" autostart="false"></script>
```

In the boot.js script inspired by [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0), change de javascript like this

```
Blazor.start({
  circuit: { configureSignalR: builder => builder.withUrl('_blazor', 4), reconnectionHandler...
```

4 = long polling